# Pandas: Get mean of different rows when columns are equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the mean of values in different rows, grouped by similarities in other columns. Example:

```
In [14]: pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,1,2], 'col2':['A','C','A','B'], 'col3':[1, 5, 6, 9]})
Out[14]: 
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    A     1
1     2    C     5
2     1    A     6
3     2    B     9
```

What I would like is to add a column with the means of col3, for all rows where the combination of col1 and col2 match. Desired output:

```
Out[14]: 
   col1 col2  col3   mean
0     1    A     1    3.5
1     2    C     5    5
2     1    A     6    3.5
3     2    B     9    9
```

I have tried several things with `groupby` in combination with `apply` but couldn't get proper results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its a `transform` my man

```
df['mean'] = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).col3.transform('mean')
```

Comment: Should `pd.groupby` be `df.groupby`?